# Error in Reading File from mentioned Directory (Python 3.2)

Tags: python

For the Code posted below

I have kept a notepad document called nd1.txt in the Folder C:\TempFiles

```
import os,file,storage
database = file.dictionary()
tools = storage.misc()
lui = -1

def sendWord(wrd, findex):
    global lui
    if findex!=lui:
        tools.refreshRecentList()
        lui = findex
    if tools.mustIgnore(wrd)==0 and tools.toRecentList(wrd)==1:
        database.addWord(wrd,findex)        
def showPostingsList():
    database.display()

def parseFile(nfile, findex):
    for line in nfile:
        pl = line.split()
        for word in pl:
            print(word)
            sendWord(word.lower(),findex)

def parseDirectory():
    files = [open(f) for f in os.listdir('C:\TempFiles')]
    findex = 0
    for nf in files:
        parseFile(nf,findex)
        findex+=1

def main():
    parseDirectory()
    showPostingsList()

main()
```

Now whenever i'm executing the code, i get the following error msg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\postingsList.py", line 39, in <module>
main()
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\postingsList.py", line 36, in main
parseDirectory(dirname)
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\postingsList.py", line 28, in parseDirectory
files = [open(f) for f in os.listdir('C:\TempFiles')]
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\postingsList.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
files = [open(f) for f in os.listdir('C:\TempFiles')]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nd1.txt'
```

Even though the file IS there in the mentioned folder, plus every function is working correctly, i've checked with dummy data

Can anyone please tell me where my code went wrong?

Comment: please use spaces, not tabs, when indenting Python code (or at least replace them before posting it anywhere). I've edited your code to apply proper indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` gives you names of the files, not full paths. You need to add the path before calling `open`, ideally using `os.path.join`.

Comment: Using open(os.path.join('C:\TempFiles',f))?

Answer (score 0):

As volferine mentioned, `os.listdir` only gives [names of files](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

You'll want to take a look at the `os.path.abspath` [module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath).

Additionally, it's worthwhile to use some logging code to figure things out -

```
import os,file,storage
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
database = file.dictionary()
tools = storage.misc()
lui = -1

def sendWord(wrd, findex):
    global lui
    if findex!=lui:
        tools.refreshRecentList()
        lui = findex
    if tools.mustIgnore(wrd)==0 and tools.toRecentList(wrd)==1:
        database.addWord(wrd,findex)        
def showPostingsList():
    database.display()

def parseFile(nfile, findex):
    for line in nfile:
        pl = line.split()
        for word in pl:
            print(word)
            sendWord(word.lower(),findex)

def parseDirectory():
    files = [open(f) for f in os.listdir('C:\TempFiles')]
    findex = 0
    logging.debug(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
    for nf in files:
        logging.debug(os.path.exists(nf))
        parseFile(nf,findex)
        findex+=1

def main():
    parseDirectory()
    showPostingsList()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `os.listdir` will return the file name not file path. You'd better add `C:\TempFiles\` before the file name